# How UIImageView in iOS 9.3 rendering an UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In iOS 9.3, I have a square UIImageView (200x200, for example), and I try to assign an UIImage (1x1 pixel) with cornerRadius,  and UIImageView become a circle. I think the problem came from UIImageView when rendering.

```
photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.jpeg"]; // 1px height x 1 px width
photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
// It can fixed with the below code
// photoImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.jpeg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2 topCapHeight:2];
// photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

If I change contentMode to ScaleAspectFill or ScaleToFill, or change the size of UIImage (2x2), or iOS version below 9.3, it works like I expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNDaM.png

The project: [download the sample projec](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6uT_8a_m6v4QWlpU1RXaWp3ZVE)

Red: Real result.
Green: Expected.

Can somebody explain the reason of it? Thank you.

Comment: set photoImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 0):

try it by changing your corner radius value

```
photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone"]; // 1px height x 1 px width
photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Even I set cornerRadius to 1, it still render circle. I can fix the problem, but I don't know the reason, I just need to know why the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

Set masksToBounds=YES

```
 photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
```

And set imageview mode Aspect Fill or Aspect Fit.

Comment: Thank Mitesh. 
I don't intend to got an circle UIImageView, but I got a circle. And I don't know why I got a circle?

Comment: set another image to you UIimageView and check it.  photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0; photoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES; i check your project and its working . see this . in you project you set clipstobound=yes so imageview became circle.

Comment: Hi Mitesh, what is the dimension of "1.jpg"? Do you try a 1x1 image on iOS 9.3?

Comment: Yes i set 1x1 image in imageview. if view mode is scale to fill then imageview become a circle so set mode to Aspect fill or Aspect Fit as you required

Comment: Yeah, that is. My question is about that: why view mode is ScaleToFill, then ImageView become a circle.

Comment: i think there is something problem related to constraint you set. i checked different possibilities in your project.i also checked without constraints it gives output on the basis of radius we set instead of circle image.